# Mudança de ambiente

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, netbeans, visual-basic-6

Estou migrando de ambiente, de VB.NET para Java (NetBeans), porém inda não sei se algumas das possibilidades do .NET podem ser realizadas no Java com Netbeans.

A minha primeira dúvida se concretiza na possibilidade de compilar um projeto um uma `.dll` e referenciá-la em outro projeto para seu consumo. Tal funcionalidade pode ser realizada no ambiente Java?

A minha outra duvida é na forma como os projetos são publicados, no .net a saída padrão é .exe instalador com auto-update, existe alguma forma de fazer o mesmo ou algo parecido no ambiente java netbeans ?

Desejo enfatizar que é meu objetivo é a utilização de múltiplas plataformas, mais especificamente Windows 7+ ou Linux Ubuntu (última versão), evitando se possível, algum caminho que leve a uma versão de software para cada plataforma específica.

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Existe alguma razão em especial para ter escolhido Java? Precisa ser Java? Você está migrando sistemas existentes para Java ou está começando a desenvolver novos sistemas em Java? O novo sistemas precisa ser desktop ou web? Ele será usado na Internet ou numa intranet? Qual a frequência de atualização esperada?

Comment: Obrigado, existem duas razões principais que motivaram a escolha, primeiramente é que o baixo custo com ambiente, que até onde eu saiba é gratuito, e a segunda é a capacidade de rodar esses sistemas tanto em windows como linux. O foco dessa migração ocorre somente com sistemas desktop, que terão acesso à internet, o sistema já existe na linguagem vb.net e pretendo reescrever ele por completo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Em geral, Java e .NET tem muitos pontos em comum e podem atingir os mesmos objetivos embora com maior ou menor dificuldades em diferentes áreas.

Vamos por partes...

## Custo

As licenças são realmente um impeditivo? O recurso mais caro quase sempre é o humano. É comum empresas tentarem evitar de gastar com licenças e depois terem que contratar mais gente para fazer o mesmo que a ferramenta poderia ter feito, só que gastando alguns meses a mais.

Em contrapartida, a Microsoft tem criado algumas licenças amigáveis com desenvolvedores, *startups* e empresas pequenas, muitas vezes gratuitas. Sugiro você consultar se realmente não poderia usar tais ferramentas.

Em geral, um bom ambiente Java pode ser todo gratuito e muitas empresas sérias usam somente ferramentas abertas e gratuitas, mas tomar essa decisão baseando-se apenas no custo de licenças não é uma boa ideia e em geral é preciso gente experiente gastando um bom tempo pensando para tomar essa decisão de forma acertada.

Considere ainda o custo de aprender uma nova plataforma. Existe uma razão porque programadores Java geralmente são contratados para vagas de Java e respectivamente para outras plataformas. Não significa que não dê para aprender, mas até que lá vários erros básicos terão sido cometidos e a produtividade será baixa.

## IDEs

Java tem boas IDEs gratuitas. As mais conhecidas e usadas são:

- Eclipse, a IDE mais usada e com a maior comunidade
- Netbeans, que nem de longe é *sinônimo* de Java, mas é mantida pela Oracle e, na minha opinião, contém as funções mais pertinentes ao mundo *corporate*, sendo portanto mais parecido com o Visual Studio em certos aspectos.

Por outro lado, existem IDEs pagas para Java também, tal como o IntelliJ IDEA, que na minha opinião é melhor que os demais em vários aspectos, embora isso não signifique que os outros não tenham suas vantagens.

Mas, por melhores que sejam as IDEs em Java, elas não vão ser melhores em tudo em relação ao Visual Studio. Uma das razões porque isso acontece é que em Java existem muitas formas diferentes de se fazer as coisas e as IDEs somente vão dar suporte a algumas poucas mais usadas.

Em geral o Visual Studio e outras ferramentas da Microsoft vão ter muitas funções mais mastigadas, enquanto em Java você vai ter que pesquisar algum framework ou biblioteca que faça a mesma coisa.

Quanto ao Netbeans, você verá abaixo que ele parece dar suporte ao que você precisa, mas como isso se compara com o que você tem no Visual Studio somente um especialista nas duas tecnologias pode dizer.

Uma vantagem das IDEs Java, principalmente o Eclipse, é que existe uma grande variedade de plugins para diversas finalidades. Embora você tenha lidar com uma miríade de diferentes fornecedores, pelo menos você tem mais change de encontrar o que precisa, talvez com mais de uma alternativa.

## Aplicações desktop

Java possui diferentes formas de se fazer interface gráfica. A tecnologia mais usada para aplicações multiplataforma chama-se Swing. Porém, a tecnologia mais atual chama-se [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html).

Muitas empresas usam essas tecnologias com sucesso para criar interfaces gráficas para aplicações desktop multiplataforma.

No Java em geral eu não recomendo você contar 100% com um editor visual "clique-e-arraste" que faça tudo por você. A abordagem de construir a interface gráfica via código é quase predominante nas aplicações Java.

O Netbeans dá suporte ao desenvolvimento tanto [com Swing](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html) como [com JavaFX](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/javafx.html), mas cada um tem um nível diferente de suporte por parte da IDE.

## Instalação e atualização

A questão aqui é *como distribuir sua aplicação*.

### Instalador

O próprio Netbeans é feito em Java e possui um instalador. Várias outras ferramentas fazem o mesmo.

Para Windows, você pode fazer isso manualmente empacotando seu sistema e usando uma ferramenta gratuita de instalação, tal como o [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

O Netbeans também possui [uma forma de criar um instalador nativo](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html).

Existem ainda outras ferramentas, algumas gratuitas e outras pagas, para criar esses instaladores.

### Java Web Start

Se estivesse no seu lugar, consideraria deixar de lado a abordagem "antiga" de distribuição e, se possível, adotar uma tecnologia mais moderna.

Se um sistema web não for possível, você pode ainda usar a tecnologia [Java Web Start](https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml). Isso consiste em disponibilizar sua aplicação num link da web.

Basicamente você disponibiliza uma URL para seus clientes. Quando um cliente acessar essa URL (tendo o Java corretamente instalado), sua aplicação será automaticamente baixada e iniciada. Novas versões serão automaticamente baixadas.

## Multiplataforma

Um sistema em Java tem todo o potencial para funcionar em qualquer ambiente suportado pela máquina virtual, mas obviamente existem alguns pontos a se tomar cuidado.

Se você conhecer os dois ambientes isso fica mais óbvio, mas é sempre bom manter um processo de testes que englobe os dois ambientes.

Alguns dos problemas comuns envolvem:

- Usar componentes visuais nativos do sistema operacionais (AWT).
- Esperar que certas fontes estejam disponíveis.
- Esperar que certos diretórios estejam disponíveis (`/tmp` ou `c:\temp`).
- Os componentes visuais podem apresentar diferenças entre diferentes sistemas, portanto não confie na quantidade exata de pixels de cada componente.
- Concatenar diretamente barras em caminhos (e.g.: `base + "/" + subdir`).
- Não especificar **sempre** o *encoding*, pois o Java vai usar a codificação do sistema operacional que é diferente para cada sistema
- Falha ao manter um padrão no tratamento de quebras de linha

Em geral, aplicações Java não precisam de diretivas ou condicionais para funcionar em diferentes plataformas, a não ser que você precise executar ferramentas externas.

## Componentização

Como regra geral, Java não gera DLLs nem executável em si mesmo.

Classes Java são compiladas para `bytecode` nos arquivos `.class`. Tais classes compiladas geralmente são agrupadas em arquivos `.jar`.

Você pode criar quantos projetos quiser e gerar um Jar a partir de cada um. A aplicação final seria uma composição de um conjunto desses arquivos `.jar`.

Lembre-se de que gerenciar vários projetos ou bibliotecas e suas versões pode ser uma tarefa complexa. Em Java, geralmente utilizamos uma ferramenta para isso, sendo a mais comum chamada [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Você pode ler um pouco mais sobre o Maven no meu artigo:

> [Instalando, configurando e usando o Maven para gerenciar suas dependências e seus projetos Java](http://luizricardo.org/2014/06/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-maven-para-gerenciar-suas-dependencias-e-seus-projetos-java/)

Comment: Entendi, realmente agradeço por sua explicação mais que completa sobre o assunto e garanto que vou pensar melhor na minha decisão graças a isso. Muito obrigado

Comment: Excelente explicação !!